# Set state values before initialization for state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I'm using [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) to manage approvals on an `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

I'm using custom `state` values so I can store states as integers. This works well, except that I am getting the following warning (from `StateMachine::Machine`) on Rails startup:

```
# Both MyClass and its :state machine have defined a different default
# for "state". Use only one or the other for defining defaults to avoid
# unexpected behaviors.
```

I'm not observing any unexpected behaviors, so this isn't a big deal. I know that I could remove the `:default` value from my table schema (e.g., `:default => 0`) to make this error go away, but I would prefer to do it on the `state_machine` side.

Here is the `state_machine` code (in my_class.rb):

```
# ...
States = {
  :pending => 0,
  :approved => 1,
  :rejected => 2,
}

state_machine :state, :initial => :pending do
  States.each do |name, value|
    state name, :value => value
  end

  event :approve do
    transition all => :approved
  end

  event :reject do
    transition all => :rejected
  end
end
```

The problem is that `state_machine` wants to set the initial/default value to "pending" before it realizes that the default value should actually be 0.

Is it possible to define my states pre-initialization? It would be nice if I could pass `State` objects or a `StateCollection` to the `Machine` initializer, but it doesn't look like that is possible (looking at the source at https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/blob/master/lib/state_machine/machine.rb).

Comment: I am not quite get it, I think remove `:initial => :pending` will solve your problem, am I right?

Comment: @MikeLi I thought that would work also, but state_machine creates an `initial_state` even when the `:initial` option is absent. This empty initial state looks like `#<StateMachine::State name=nil value=nil initial=true context=[]>`, which still triggers the warning message above. Thanks though.

Comment: It's odd, cause I create a sample app with the code you provide, but I didn't get the warning you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for looking into this--I really appreciate the help. I've realized that the issue is related to the db connection being established on initialization. I've opened a separate question for that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154429/when-does-activerecord-establish-connections. In my application, state_machine's `owner_class_attribute_default` returns the default value (0), whereas in a new sample app it returns `nil`.