# When does ActiveRecord establish connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In some of my Rails applications, my ActiveRecord models seem to establish db connections on initialization (e.g., when I do `rails console`), while in others connections seem to be established only when I reference the model class or instantiate a model object.

For example, I just went to one application, opened Rails console and wrote:

```
SomeModel.connected?
```

and it returned `false`. I went to another application, entered the same command (for a different model), and it returned `true`. I went to a third application and entered the same command. This time, it waited a moment and then returned `true`, which made me think that the `connected?` method triggered the connection for some reason.

This difference in behavior doesn't seem related to Rails versions or the contents of the models. It could be something weird I've done in my initializers, but I don't think so.

So when does Rails establish connections? Or what is the expected behavior?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I'll add that it doesn't seem like `connected?` returns false because Rails **cannot** connect to the database.

For example, in my first application I do:

```
SomeModel.connected?
# => false
SomeModel.table_exists? # or any other command that makes Rails look at db
# => true
SomeModel.connected?
# => true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Whether a database connection is actually initialized during the Rails initialization process depends basically on whether `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` (not `establish_connection`) is called during the initialization process.

This can be related to the Rails version: for example, in Rails 3.2.13, the "active_record.validate_explain_support" initializer makes a call to `connection`:

```
!ActiveRecord::Base.connection.supports_explain?
```

In Rails 3.2.14, this call is not made.

However, Rails 3.2.14 may make a call to `connection` in the "active_record.set_reloader_hooks" initializer. This call may occur with the command

```
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_cache!
```

although the `prepare` callback runner doesn't always seem to call this...

I also found that some gems (e.g., `ActiveAdmin`) have an initialization process that will call `connection` at some point.

Comment: Possibly related commits https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7423a71fc02c0ca3bf37b94e16a1322c0caaa6fd, https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/85cc7122bab1cfec661fdfe3bf4738d9fba55399. Sadly the latter is not backported to 3.2.x

Comment: And this commit as well: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3688e02ca52c0b72d3092e8498da51e06b7fc58

Comment: @sayap, hey thanks for the links. Those really help explain the intended/expected behavior

Comment: @kardeiz, Can you point out which gems did something like this? I mean which lines of code of those gems. I can't find any inside active_admin.

Comment: @Chamnap, as part of the initialization process, AA loads its routes, which initializes a `Resource`, which calls `primary_key` on an AR class, which calls `table_exists?`, which calls the `connection` method mentioned above. If you put `puts caller` in `AR::Base.connection` you should see something similar.

Comment: @kardeiz, Thanks for reply. I have my rails engine which contains only models. It's used in several rails 4 apps. When I go to rails console of those, it appears the same thing (no connection). I'm not really sure what is going on. However, when doing rails server, it's okay. Right now, I need to invoke this: console do ActiveRecord::Base.clear_cache! end. Are you doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot offer you exact solutions because there could be several reasons why there are some discrepancies.

Assuming you haven't rewrote `connected?` method, it returns true when a Rails model can establish connection to its backend. Note that when I say backend, it can be local database in your machine, remote database in your VPN at your work, or remote database far away provided by Amazon RDS. It can differ based on your Rails environments, database config, and Rails app. So the time it takes to check its connection can differ from case to case.

It will return false when it cannot establish connection to its backend. Again, this could be due to many reasons. Your database config might be incorrect. Your remote database might be down. It might be expected by design also. For example, if you have a model using activemodel, but use json to communicate with some API instead of conventional database, it'll return false because the model table is not in the database.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case it is not a database connection issue--see my additional info above. I haven't rewritten `connected?` or any other `ActiveRecord` methods.

Comment: Does your schema.rb match your database exactly?

Comment: Yes (I'm just using SQLite).